# custom components in loadUI

Tags: loadui

How can I add custom components into loadUI please?

I want to download the HTTP Runner component. In the zip file, there is a .png and groovy script file.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Extract the contents of the zip file into the script-components
>   directory in your loadUI installation, and the component should show
>   up in the Component toolbar.

I tried this for the custom HTTP runner component, and it immediately showed up in the runners toolbar on the LHS (didn't even have to restart loadUI).

source: http://htpwww.eviware.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=11220